# How do I use postgres in a Rails app template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm creating a custom template for an app, and I added pg to be used instead of sqlite:

```
gem 'pg'

gsub_file "Gemfile", /^gem\s+["']sqlite3["'].*$/,''

after_bundle do
  generate "rspec:install"
  generate "simple_form:install"
end
```

However, if I create the application like this, the database.yml file if going to be configured for sqlite3 by default, how can I specify the app to add the configuration for `postgresql` instead from my template? just as I were adding the `--database=postgresql` option

Comment: I edited the title since it does not really have anything to do with RSpec - the error just happens to pop up when you run `rspec:install`. I think it might be because the `database.yml` file still has `sqlite` listed as the adapter.

Comment: I ran --database=postgresql when creating the app, and the `database.yml` has `postgresql` as the adapter

Comment: Okay, this had nothing to do with templates, I had to install the sqlite3 gem even if i'm not using it

Comment: 1. After looking at your last comment, I'm wondering whether this question has been solved, and 2. if it has not been solved, could you show your `database.yml` file (with passwords eliminated, of course :) )? I've seen your comment above about `database.yml`, but I still think it would be potentially helpful to have a look.

Comment: Yes, the error had nothing to do with this, I had to install the gem. I updated the question, as I'd like to run the template and use postgresql without any extra steps or options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't needed to ask the user for the application name, as `app_name` is already populated with it.

[Thor](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor/) commands are incredibly helpful for working with files, it is possible to use `.erb` templates and pass them values from your template, using the [template method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor/Actions#template-instance_method):

```
# config the app to use postgres
remove_file 'config/database.yml'
template 'database.erb', 'config/database.yml'
```

database.erb:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  host: db 
  port: 5432
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  user: postgres
  password: postgres

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= app_name %>_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= app_name %>_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= app_name %>_production
```

Comment: In case you want to look how rails itself is selecting it depending on the value of the --database option, have a look at the file rails/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb (rails version 5.1.0.alpha).

Answer (score 0):

I do mine a little differently. Here's my `template.rb`.

```
remove_file 'config/database.yml'

file 'config/database.yml', <<-CODE
  # PostgreSQL. Versions 9.1 and up are supported.
  #
  # Install the pg driver:
  #   gem install pg
  # On OS X with Homebrew:
  #   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
  # On OS X with MacPorts:
  #   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
  # On Windows:
  #   gem install pg
  #       Choose the win32 build.
  #       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
  #
  # Configure Using Gemfile
  # gem 'pg'
  #
  default: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
    # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

  development:
    <<: *default
    database: foo_development

    # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
    # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
    # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
    # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
    #username: foo

    # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
    #password:

    # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
    # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
    # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
    #host: localhost

    # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
    # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
    #port: 5432

    # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
    #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

    # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
    #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
    #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
    # Defaults to warning.
    #min_messages: notice

  # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
  # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
  # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
  test:
    <<: *default
    database: foo_test

  # As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
  # like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
  # ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
  #
  # Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
  # the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
  # for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
  # production deployment.
  #
  # On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
  # available as an environment variable. For example:
  #
  #   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
  #
  # You can use this database configuration with:
  #
  #   production:
  #     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  #
  production:
    <<: *default
    database: foo_production
    username: foo
    password: <%= ENV['FOO_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
CODE
```